# Copying Spark Dataframe to Google Cloud Bigtable using Java/Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-bigtable

I am using Spark for my big data operations and I would like to copy my Spark data-frame to Google Cloud Bigtable.

Are there any examples/libraries/APIs which can help me achieve this? Either in Java or Scala ?

A Java or Scala example would be really helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Google Cloud Bigtable supports the Apache HBase 1.0+ APIs, so you can use the Apache Spark HBase connector. There are several examples here:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/scala

Note that these examples are written using [Google Cloud Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/), Google Cloud's hosted/managed Hadoop + Spark service, but they should work fine for a standalone Spark setup.

Comment: thank you for the link. I now have the examples. I am running Spark in stand alone mode and I would like to establish connection using my credentials JSON file. I was searching for documentation to connect to Big Table using JSON credentials but I could not find any. Do you know of any links that would help me solve that problem?

Comment: I used your documentation link and ran into some issue. I have created the issue on Github too. Here is the link -- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/issues/287